# Adespatial and betapart return different values for what seems to be the same task

Tags: r

I just found a question on Researchgate, why `adespatial`'s `beta.div.comp(..., coef="BJ", quant=FALSE)` and `betapart`'s `beta.multi(..., index.family="jaccard")` return different output, despite one would assume the functions run similar calculations, given the index family is set to `"jaccard"` and the method of Baselga et al is used.

So I tested the following:

```
require("ade4")
data(doubs)
A = doubs$fish[-8,]
A <- ifelse(A > 0, 1, 0)

require("adespatial")
beta.div.comp(A, coef="BJ", quant=FALSE)$part
```

Resulting in:

```
     BDtotal         Repl          Nes Repl/BDtotal  Nes/BDtotal 
   0.3258676    0.1674413    0.1584263    0.5138323    0.4861677
```

Whereas when I now ran

```
require("betapart")
beta.multi(A, index.family="jaccard")
```

it returns

```
$beta.JTU
[1] 0.7885784

$beta.JNE
[1] 0.1470249

$beta.JAC
[1] 0.9356033
```

Obviously, the values are not in the same order, but also they are completely different.

So I went to github and copied the code from the relevant functions of both packages. I changed variable names where variables had a pendant in the other package, to indicate which values or parts of the script are basically the same for both packages.
This is the result:

```
require("adespatial")
require("betapart")
require("ade4")
# load some example data
data(doubs)
A = doubs$fish[-8,]
A <- ifelse(A > 0, 1, 0)

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#### adespatial
### beta.div.comp
# first, run the function
beta.div.comp(A, coef="BJ", quant=FALSE)

## what it does:
n <- nrow(A)
a <- A %*% t(A)
b <- A %*% (1 - t(A))
c <- (1 - A) %*% t(A)
min.bc <- pmin(b, c)
D <- (b + c) / (a + b + c)               # Jaccard dissimilarity
repl <- 2 * min.bc / (a + 2 * min.bc)    # replacement, turnover
rich <- D - repl

D <- as.dist(D)
repl <- as.dist(repl)
rich <- as.dist(rich)

## output values:
# turnover/replacement
total.div <- sum(D) / (n * (n - 1))     # == mean(D) / 2
# nestedness
repl.div <- sum(repl) / (n * (n - 1))   # == mean(repl) / 2
# total
rich.div <- sum(rich) / (n * (n - 1))   # == mean(rich) / 2

## the following produces the same values using betapart:
mean(beta.pair(A, index.family = "jaccard")$beta.jac) / 2
mean(beta.pair(A, index.family = "jaccard")$beta.jtu) / 2
mean(beta.pair(A, index.family = "jaccard")$beta.jne) / 2

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#### betapart
### beta.multi
# first, run the function
beta.multi(A, index.family="jaccard")

## what it does:
a <- A %*% t(A)
c <-  abs(sweep(a, 2, diag(a)))
sumSi <- sum(diag(a))                   # species by site richness
St <- sum(colSums(A) > 0)               # regional species richness; or ncol(A), if all columns contain values > 0
ms.a <- sumSi - St                      # multi site shared species term

max.bc <- pmax(c, t(c))
min.bc <- pmin(c, t(c))

sum.max.bc <- sum(max.bc[lower.tri(max.bc)]) # == sum(as.dist(max.bc))
sum.min.bc <- sum(min.bc[lower.tri(min.bc)]) # == sum(as.dist(min.bc))

## output values:
# turnover/replacement
beta.jtu <- (2 * sum.min.bc) / (ms.a + (2 * sum.min.bc))
# nestedness
beta.jne <- (ms.a / (ms.a + (2 * sum.min.bc))) * ((sum.max.bc - sum.min.bc) / ((ms.a) + sum.max.bc + sum.min.bc))
# total
beta.jac <- (sum.min.bc + sum.max.bc) / (ms.a + sum.min.bc + sum.max.bc)
```

As you can see, there are some basic equations (the ones described in the relevant papers on the partitioning of beta diversity), which are similar for both approaches. However, the `adespatial` function first calculates some diversity matrices and then sums them up while the `betapart` approach first summarises the input matrix to obtain single values and then applies the equations for betadiversity decomposition.

Now, my question would be: Why are there different outputs? Are there errors in the code, or are the functions supposed to behave differently?

Answer (score 0):

I found in Baselga (2012; doi: 10.1111/j.1466-8238.2011.00756.x) that `beta.multi` uses a multiple-site version of the dissimilarity measures, listed in Table 2 of his paper. `beta.div.comp`, on the other hand, basically does averaging of the pairwise dissimilarities. Those are different approaches that lead to different results.